# Capturing/Logging image related data using Django/Python

Tags: c#, asp.net, python, django, runatserver

I come from a ASP.Net background and taking baby steps in open source world. I have an image based application and for every image click I want to log data on server. I'm using Django/Python to host this application.

My understanding is that I need to process this data on client side and send to server using Ajax calls. Please correct me if I'm wrong. In ASP.net world, we had "runat=server" tag for every HTML control that  made logging data on server really easy. Is there something similar in Django/Python?

Also, what is the most efficient way of logging image data in this situation?

Thanks in advance. Your help is highly appreciated.

Cheers!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your understanding of needing to use AJAX calls is one correct answer.

You could also register `onclick` JavaScript events for all images and have the JavaScript call a function that submits a form with the needed values for the view to process. That's sort of [how ASP.net's PostBack works](http://www.xefteri.com/articles/show.cfm?id=18). The only difference is you're writing the client-side code yourself and nothing is obfuscated with the `__VIEWSTATE` hidden field.

Basically, ASP.net and Django come from two very different schools of thought. ASP.net's `runat=server` stuff makes things accessible to the various Page Lifecycle Events (Init, PreLoad, Render, etc) using helpful nuggets from `__VIEWSTATE`.

Django has no such Page Lifecycle model. It keeps things much simpler: a request is directed to a view method (or class-based view) using `urls.py`. The view method then returns a response.

There are benefits and drawbacks to both ways of doing things.

The short answer is that different frameworks tend to solve the same problem in different ways.